# Way of setting instance variable for unit testing

Tags: ios, unit-testing, instance-variables

I have a class named TimePass subclass of NSObject. It has a property

```
NSString *name
```

in (.m) file of TimePass I defined a constructor for my property name

```
-(NSString *) name {
    self.name = @"aseem";
    return self.name;
}
```

It gives me an error when I test its `XCTAssertNotNil` in unit testing class. I am testing if it's `nil`. If I replace `self.name` with `_name` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to override the setter for the property like you did because you'll likely end up in an infinite loop. Consider your method:

```
- (NSString *)name {
   self.name = @"aseem";
   return self.name;
}
```

You set self.name to @"aseem", and then return self.name, so when you actually do anything with self.name, you actually *call* the name method you just created, thus you set self.name to aseem again and tell it to return self.name, calling the method again, so on and so forth. In a nutshell, using the _name instance variable in the return bypasses calling the function over and over again, and simply returns the string you just set.

Rather than create a property, just use an instance variable like this:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface YourTestClass : XCTestCase {
    NSString *_name;
}

@end

@implementation YourTestClass

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    _name = @"aseem";
}


@end
```